# ¿Como debuggear un servicio Windows en C# con Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net, servicio

Esta es mi primera pregunta, perdón si cometo algún error al formularla.

Tengo un servicio Windows programado por mi antecesor. Aun soy inexperto en .net Y quiero debuggear el servicio para entenderlo mejor pero no me funciona. El metodo Main es como sigue:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
        {
        new ClaseConOnStart()
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Completando la respuesta de Leandro, cuando yo he tenido que depurar algun servicio windows me ha resultado muy útil el siguiente método:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

[Debugger.Launch](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch?view=netframework-4.7.2) lo que hace es que lanza el depurador en el lugar del código donde se ejecuta. De esa manera, si hay alguna parte de tu servicio que quieres depurar, puedes ejecutar ese método y automáticamente se abrirá el visual studio para que puedas hacerlo.

Para que solo se lance en depuración, es bueno usar `DEBUG`:

```
#if DEBUG
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes analizar el codigo de forma remota adjuntandote al proceso del servicio de windows.

El primer paso seria publicas compilado en `debug`, porque se necesitan que esten presente los archivos `.pdb` de las `dll`

Luego desde el `Visual Studio` podras adjuntarte al proceso del servicio para analizar el codigo.

[Asociar con procesos en ejecución con el depurador de Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/debugger/attach-to-running-processes-with-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2017)

Usas la opcion del menu

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Al final he usado el #if DEBUG, gracias por la ayuda!

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        #if DEBUG
           Helpers.ProcesoPrincipal.Run();
        #else
           ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
           ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
           {
            new ClaseConOnStart()
           };
         ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        #endif

    }
```

Revisando el código entendí que la clase que creaba el servicio ("ClaseConOnStart") ejecutaba los métodos de otra clase que contenía todo el proceso del servicio ("ProcesoPrincipal") entonces solo depuré directamente esta clase, su método "Run()" específicamente que es el que tiene el proceso principal.